# In use vee-validate library vue-select element does not work

Tags: validation, vuejs2

In vuejs 2.5 application I use vee-validate library ( http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/examples.html ) with inputs like:

```
<template>
    <section>


        <form @submit.prevent="validateBeforeSubmit" class="form-horizontal">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                    <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 control-label" for="name">Name<span class="required"> * </span></label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                        <input v-validate="'required|max:255'" v-model="task.name"
                               :class="{ 'form-control':true, 'input': true, 'text-danger': vueErrorsList.has('name') }" name="name" id="name"
                               type="text" placeholder="name">
                        <span v-show="vueErrorsList.has('name')" class="text-danger">{{ vueErrorsList.first('name') }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                    <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 control-label" for="category_id">Category<span class="required"> * </span></label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                        <v-select v-validate="'required'" id="category_id" name="category_id" v-model="selection_category_id" :options=categoriesSelectionList></v-select>
                        <span v-show="vueErrorsList.has('category_id')" class="text-danger">{{ vueErrorsList.first('category_id') }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </form>

    </section>
</template>


<script>
    import {bus} from '../../app';

    ...
    import vSelect from 'vue-select'

    Vue.component('v-select', vSelect) // https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select
    import moment from 'moment';


    ...
    export default {

        created() {
            this.$validator.localize(window.CURRENT_LANG, {
                attributes: {
                    selection_category_id: 'category',
                    category_id: 'category',
                    ...
                }
            });
        }, // created() {

        ...
            methods
    :
    {

        validateBeforeSubmit()
        {
            this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    this.updateTask()
                } else {
                    this.showPopupMessage('Error ' + ( this.is_insert ? 'adding' : 'updating' ) + ' task. ', 'error');
                }
            })
        }
    , // validateBeforeSubmit() {

        updateTask()
        {
        ...
        }
    , // updateTask() {


    } // methods:{

    }

</script>
```

But In the code above the second input is vue-select element ( https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select  )
and it is not validated at all.
I put

```
 v-validate="'required'"
```

to it but it does not work.
I use validateBeforeSubmit method and if there is a way to make some kind of custom validation, so I would check is value in 
select input is selected?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see `import veeValidate from 'vee-validate'` in your code. `vSelect` and `veeValidate` are two different libraries

Comment: They are different plugins. `veeValidate` expects a format that `vSelect` doesn't have. They are unlikely to work together without any workarounds.

Comment: 1) vee-validate is included in common component, as it used in many pages. Anyway vee-validate functionality works ok on this page.
2) I search such workarounds : many JS validation libs has custom validation  or even on server validation methods. Has vee-validate such methods?

Comment: Making other form I have to add <date-picker field and v-validate="'required'" does not work for this. So  vee-validate has no any custom validation methods? Any tricks possible ?